# is inet/omnet don't support support Mipv4

Tags: c++, simulation, inet

i am new for omnet++ and inet,i notice that  there ars some exmple of MIpv6,but i can't find any example about Mipv4(mobility ipv4) in Tutorials or source code ,is inet/omnet don't support support Mipv4?

where can i find the example or Tutorials about mpiv4